# Dismiss Popover When Row Selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

When selecting a row from the master view of UISPlitViewControler when its in popover mode. Isn't it supposed to dismiss automatically? How can I fix it there?

Usually I would do `[self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];` but `popoverController` isn't recognized in this case.

I thought that `UISplitViewController` is supposed to do this automatically?

Here is my UISplitViewDelegate code that is in my detailViewCOntroller:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController *)pc
{
    barButtonItem.title = @"Medical Codes";
    NSMutableArray *items = [[self.toolbar items] mutableCopy];
    [items insertObject:barButtonItem atIndex:0];
    [self.toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
    [items release];
}

// Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    NSMutableArray *items = [[self.toolbar items] mutableCopy];
    [items removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [self.toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
    [items release];
}
```

In my app delegate I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DetailViewControlleriPad *rightViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet RootViewController * leftViewController;
```

And these properties are hooked up in IB.  RootViewController pushes to other tableviews, which need to be dismissed when they are selected while in popover mode.

edit

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (detailItem != newDetailItem)
    {
        [detailItem release];
        detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];
        [self.myTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always had to explicitly dismiss the popover manually. To do this, grab a reference to the popover view controller when it is passed to my UISplitViewControllerDelegate:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc 
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController 
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem 
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc
{
    splitViewPopover = [pc retain];
    // Other stuff
}
```

Because I do this I also have to release the reference when it is no longer valid:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc 
     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController 
  invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)button 
{    
    [splitViewPopover release];
    splitViewPopover = nil;
    // Other stuff
}
```

Then, when an item has been selected in my master view controller, I update my detail controller and dismiss the popover:

```
[splitViewPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: What I have typically done is implemented the UISplitViewControllerDelegate within my main app delegate. I then have the app delegate add itself as a delegate to the master view controller. Anytime something happens in my master view controller that should result in "selection" it notifies its delegate (the main app delegate), which dismisses the popover. That way only the app delegate needs to have a splitViewPopover reference. You could probably do something similar.

Comment: I actually have those 2 methods implemented in my detail VC.  So in that case, will I have to manually pass the splitViewPopover down the heirchy of sub tableviews?

Comment: I wouldn't: I would move the implementation of that method up into the application delegate. That way the app delegate can "know" about the master VC and the detail VC, and manage the interactions between them. Use Interface Builder to assign the app controller as the delegate for both the master VC and the detailed VC, and have it manage the popover dismissal when needed.

Comment: Tim, based on the code I posted, can I just pass the object as you did in your code?

Comment: Assuming you have wired things up to notify the detail view controller when a selection has been made from the popover, you should be fine to dismiss the popover that you were passed in the splitViewController:willHideViewController method.

Comment: These delegate methods are deprecated in iOS 8. Anyone figure out how to dismiss the master view without using these methods?